# How to link to libc++ on /usr/local/lib?

Tags: c++, macos, linker, osx-mountain-lion, libc++

I've tried to provide `-L /usr/local/lib`, tried `-nostdinc++`, tried to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` but `otool` aways gives me:

```
otool -L sample
sample:
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

How to link to my custom compiled `/usr/local/lib/libc++.dylib` on OS X?

Variations of compilation were upon basic `clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've pointed out, oTool with -L is telling you that the libc++.1.dylib is being used from /usr/lib.

OSX development provides you with the command *install_name_tool*, which allows you to set the location of the required paths.

As an example, you'd use it something like this: -

```
install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib /usr/local/lib/libc++.dylib <target file>
```

where the first path is the current path, the second is the one you want to change it to and the third is the file you're changing the paths for.

Comment: Well, I've known of this solution, but it's very hacky IMO... A note should be added about the need to use `-headerpad_max_install_names` before using `install_name_tool` to change the binary. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/install_name_tool.1.html

Comment: It's not a hack, as it's clearly described in the Qt documentation: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq09-mac-deployment.html

Comment: That looks like appealing to authority, but, anyway, as I said, it's very hacky way out IMO. It's sad if it's the only option and one is unable to set library search path priority that works, the same way one is able to do for executable search path priority through `'/etc/paths'`

Comment: I must also take a look at the `-R` option (or the `LD_RUN_PATH` environment variable) to see whether it works at the compilation/linking command when I'm back at home.

Comment: While its not the cleanest way of doing things, allowing the changing of paths like that does provide a lot of flexibility, allowing libs and frameworks to be placed in either general locations, or inside the app bundle itself, with relative ease of changing which one is used.

Comment: Yeah, `-R` doesn't work. Only `install_name_tool` and `-headerpad_max_install_names` to the rescue...