# What determines linking behaviour for GHC on OS X?

Tags: macos, haskell, ghc, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I'm observing different linking behaviour between two machines when compiling a binary.

Each has the same GHC (7.8.3), same code, same flags (`-Wall -O2`), same libgmp (installed by Homebrew on each):

```
machine-one$ otool -L my-binary
my-binary:
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
        /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)

machine-two$ otool -L my-binary
my-binary:
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
        /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
        /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib (compatibility version 13.0.0, current version 13.0.0)
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why `libgmp` is linked dynamically on the second machine.

In terms of differences I've been able to recognize: GHC has been installed via the [binary distribution for OS X](http://www.haskell.org/ghc) on the first machine and Homebrew on the second.  For C compilers, we have:

```
machine-one$ cc --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.51) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix

machine-two$ cc --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

What typically determines the linking behaviour, and how can I enforce one linking method or the other?

**EDIT**: I've observed the same behaviour happening with `zlib` on yet another machine, so it's not a GMP-specific issue.

**EDIT**: I've plucked `ghc --info` from each of the machines, here they are for [machine one](https://gist.github.com/jtobin/dc1ff9f4837be7a6b68a) and [machine two](https://gist.github.com/jtobin/dc0ca1993a209d39a04e).  And here's [the diff](https://gist.github.com/jtobin/aed0dba674f46f9bdd41) between the two as well.

**EDIT**: I've reinstalled ghc on machine two via the distribution binary, and sure enough `libgmp` is *not* dynamically linked when I recompile my binary.  So it seems like this is related to installing GHC via Homebrew.

Still quite interested in what's going on exactly.

Comment: I think it might depend in part on how GHC was compiled. Could the two distributions you used have been compiled differently?

Comment: A similar question: [(link)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539857/statically-link-gmp-to-an-haskell-application-using-ghc-llvm) which might help.

Comment: @dfeuer GHC was indeed installed differently - via a binary vs via Homebrew - but I can't find any information on what to expect there in either case.

@user5402 I understand that one can't pass the static linking flags on OS X as there's no way to statically link `libSystem` and `libiconv`.

Comment: Can you add the output of command 'ghc --info' to your question?

Comment: Interesting. Machine one is using gcc as Haskell C Compiler, while #2 uses clang. They are also using different linkers. Although I would have thought that would have no effect when using native compilation mode (which is the default, I think)

Comment: Reading the diff https://gist.github.com/jtobin/aed0dba674f46f9bdd41 the official distribution was compiled with ```/usr/bin/gcc``` while the homebrew version with ```clang```
This discusses installing gcc vs clang http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128298/homebrew-gcc-llvm-and-c11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crucial difference is that machine #2 has `/usr/local/lib` in the linker path, and is using brew's linker (`/usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/ld`). `ghc` still uses an external linker, even if it isn't using the C backend for code generation, so you can combine Haskell code with code written in other languages (crucial for Haskell's many FFI bindings to third-party libraries). So you should really be asking the brew people why things get linked differently. It's not actually a `ghc` issue.